# Ubuntu 20.04 don't recognize my Asus MB169B+ USB 3.0 Monitor (Works well in Win10)

Tags: drivers, 20.04, multiple-monitors

I have a USB 3.0 Portable Monitor that works well under Windows 10, but when I reboot the same laptop under Ubuntu 20.04, it's not recognized.

I have installed it's drivers as mentioned below.

1. Downloaded the Asus MB169B+ Driver:

   https://www.asus.com/ca-en/Monitors/MB169BPlus/HelpDesk_Download/

   Version 5.3.1 2020/06/15

   https://dlcdnets.asus.com/pub/ASUS/LCD%20Monitors/MB16AP/ASUS_MB_Series_driver_for_Ubuntu_5.3.1.zip
2. Extracted the zip file:

   ASUS_MB_Series_driver_for_Ubuntu_5.3.1.zip
3. Ran the command to make it executable: `chmod 755 displaylink-driver-5.3.1.34.run`
4. Executed the command: `sudo ./displaylink-driver-5.3.1.34.run`
5. Install completed, rebooted the machine
6. Monitor still in idle mode (orange button - if it was recognized, it would be white)

FYI - I don't have a graphic card, just the one embedded in the Intel i5 6th gen

Comment: `chmod +x` is how you make a file executable; `chmod 755` sets permissions to rwxr-xr-x

Comment: Does the monitor show up in display settings? Maybe you need to enable it first. How long did you wait after boot? The driver's release notes mention a firmware upgrade for some models that will be uploaded in the background: "The upgrade is silent, therefore screens connected to DL-6xxx, DL-5xxx, DL-3xxx or DL-41xx devices may require a few seconds to appear when devices are connected for the first time, or after devices have been used on other platforms and OSes."

Comment: No the monitor don't show up in the diaply settings (if it was, the power button would be white like in Windows 10, but if it remains in orange, then it means it's plugged but unknown)
I'll try to find more about the firmware, so far I'm still stuck...

Comment: Were you able to figure out a solution? I am facing the same issue.

Comment: Unfortunately no, I even open a ticket with Canonical and they told me they don't support packages outside of their repositories...
They told me to launch Ubuntu with Wayland mode activated, but still nothing...

Comment: Maybe try some of the solutions out there for older versions of ubuntu. I tried them back in the day. After upgrading to 20 i dusted off my mb168b installed the drivers and it worked fine. Didn't work for me back in 18. I'm on a X1 Thinkpad. I don't get an occassional small white box after installing the drivers though and I doesn't seem to like hover effects in browsers.

Comment: I went through most of Google Search pages and nothing seems to work... I think it's related to the Kernel, every upgrade breaks the compatibility and I guess I need to wait for Asus/DisplayLink driver update...

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with my Asus MB16AC and just found the solution.

The driver Asus gives does not work on my Xubuntu 20.04 kernel 5.13 (which is displaylink-driver-5.3.1).
I followed the instruction here:
https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/DisplayLink/
This helps me to install the displaylink-driver-5.4.1-55.174
Thereafter, my Asus MB16AC works.

Note 1: You should firstly uninstall the displaylink-driver, which does not work.
Note 2: I only tried the **alternative installer** part of the website, and it works.
Note 3: Using the english version of the website if necessary.
Note 4: This solution should work for Ubuntu 20.04 as well.
Note 5: I also use the embedded graphic chip (Intel Graphics HD 3000).

Comment: thank you, I'm running ubuntu 20.04 and this answer worked for me.  get the driver to support usb 3.0 here: https://support.displaylink.com/knowledgebase/articles/683482-displaylink-support-for-ubuntu-now-available

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem and then I found this post https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=323724

I removed the displaylink driver and libc6-dev then reinstalled libc6-dev and ran displaylink-installer:

Unplug monitor

`sudo apt-get remove libc6-dev`

`sudo displaylink-installer uninstall`

`sudo apt-get install libc6-dev`

Installed latest driver    as per Asus or    https://support.displaylink.com/knowledgebase/articles/684649

Whereas before I got errors about EVDI kernel being there already when I installed, now it installed properly.
I plugged in my monitor.

However it was still not detected when I went to Display properties.

I thought I'd try `sudo displaylink-installer` and despite the error message of Installation terminated, my MB169B+ kicked into life and appeared in Display and working properly.

I rebooted and it worked straight away.

Comment: Still nothing... I have an i5 6400U with intel graphics... Maybe it's related...