# External device does not support DP alt mode even after fresh OS installation, ASUS ZenScreen

Tags: drivers, 20.04, display, asus, usb-c

I have a ZenScreen ASUS MB16ACE works properly in WIN10 and before it worked in Ubuntu too, maybe 2 weeks ago or so it stopped with some update.  I decided to re-install OS but problem continues

When I connected to Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS it displays "Your device does not support DP alt mode: Please install the latest drivers".
I browsed and found some posts related, this one `https://askubuntu.com/questions/1265432/ubuntu-20-04-dont-recognize-my-asus-mb169b-usb-3-0-monitor-works-well-in-win1` has one workaround.
I installed latest  DisplayLink software and drivers from ASUS but it still continue without working even an device buss is assigned.

```
@PC:~/Downloads/ASUS_MB_Series_driver_for_Ubuntu_5.3.1$ lsusb -d 17e9:
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 17e9:4374 DisplayLink
```

I do not what else check, any hint, thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem after installing the asus displaylink driver (5.3.1) to connect my zenscreen MB16ACE.  It seems like the issue here is that the zenscreen is the first device I tried to connect (ubuntu ~20.04) that uses the usb 3.0 standard

Here's the displaylink driver for usb 3.0: https://support.displaylink.com/knowledgebase/articles/683482-displaylink-support-for-ubuntu-now-available

My screen started working after I installed it

Comment: Not correct I use many USB 3 and USB 2 devices on many computers every day. It may be this driver may help but not for the reason you have said.

Comment: Thanks @David, usb 3.0 is not new to ubuntu, it was just the first usb 3.0 device I used.  I fixed the answer